# Trying to save latitude and longitude to Core data causes bad access

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to save latitude and longitude in core data, but causing a bad access.
here is the code:

**EDIT :**

```
Favourites *fav = (Favourites *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favourites" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",point.title];
int index =[sharedRequest.name indexOfObject:str];
[fav setPlaceName:str];

double lat = [[sharedRequest.latArray objectAtIndex:index] doubleValue];
double lng = [[sharedRequest.lngArray objectAtIndex:index] doubleValue];

[fav setPlaceLatitude:lat];
[fav setPlaceLongitude:lng];
```

I don't know why this happening. Any help would be appreciable.

**P.S lat and lng has value when I am printing them**

Comment: Can you show the full error message? Also, are you using ARC?

Comment: Yes I am using ARC, it does not print anything on console, just notifies me that there is a bad access

Comment: Tell us what the objects are (sharedRequest, fav)? Which line does it crash on?

Comment: `sharedRequest` is a singleton class which is responsible to fetch data at back end and `fav` is the object of CoreData class

Comment: @woz yes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Can we see the code in context? I think something is happening before this to cause the problem.

Comment: @woz I didnt get you do you want to see where the context is getting intialized

Comment: I want to see what happens from the beginning of the function until the lines you posted.

Comment: @woz please see the edit part

Comment: Are you getting any warnings in Xcode when you compile?

Comment: No there are no warnings

Comment: What happens if you comment out those two lines at the end? Does it still crash. Also, add an exception breakpoint in Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

You need to save your latitude and longitude value as a NSNumber instead of a double.

```
NSNumber *latitude = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:lat];
[fav setPlaceLatitude:latitude];
```

**Update**

For your Favorites entity, placeLatitude attribute should be a double.  However, when using the NSManagedObject subclass Favorites, you need to use NSNumber to set placeLatitude.  Core Data uses NSNumber to store primitives such as int, float, double, bool.

Let Xcode generate your Favorites class.  Pick the Core Data data model on the left pane, then Xcode -> Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass.

Comment: I have set the dataType to double, so i cant use NSNumber

Comment: You **must** use NSNumber.  Otherwise it will crash.  Like it is now.

Comment: so what data type do i use in core data model

Comment: Double is what you want.  You just need so make the change I suggested.  Look at the header for your NSManagedObject Favourites and you'll see that placeLatitude is a NSNumber.

Comment: I tried to use your code, but it gives me an error `Sending NSNumber*_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'double'`

Comment: Is Favourites an object you created yourself or did Xcode create it from your Core Data model?

Comment: Favourites is class which I created for core data model and Favourites is also an entity in core data model which contains three attributes placeName,placeLatitude,placeLongitude.

Comment: Did you manually type in all the code for the Favourites class or did you use Xcode -> Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass while viewing Favourites in the Core Data model?

Comment: No, I manually typed all the code for the Favourites class. I created it as a subclass of NSObject and then adding a xcodedatamodel for core data

Comment: You probably used double when you should have used NSNumber.  Please let Xcode generate this file for you.  Select the core data data model and the pick Xcode -> Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass.

Comment: I don't think he'd be getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS trying to set an NSNumber property with a double.